# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' (d3zoom)

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm seeing errors in running tests in Angular:

```
  ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export {default as zoom} from "./zoom.js";
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

      16 | import { scaleLinear } from "d3-scale";
      17 | import { event, mouse, select, Selection } from "d3-selection";
    > 18 | import { zoom, ZoomBehavior, zoomIdentity, ZoomTransform } from "d3-zoom";
         | ^
      19 | import { Observable, Subscription } from "rxjs";
      20 | import { map, tap } from "rxjs/operators";
```

I've tried following suggestions on another SO post which suggested using a different version of node (node v.12 was recommended so I downgraded from 14 to 12) and that did not work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jest or whicheva test site u have it speaks javascript/commonjs not typescript/esmodules. What I mean is you need to use require if you want to write them tests with typescript install ts-node
`npm i -D ts-node` but I think there is already a ts-jest package